# Writing version adaptive code with System.XXX.dll in UWP

Tags: uwp

I am developing a UWP app with Min Version 15063 (Creators Update) and Target Version 16299 (Fall Creators Update). Somewhere in the app, I would like to enumerate network adapters of the machine. This functionality needs to work only in desktop environment (which has relatively newer Windows 10 version). But I would to support other functionalities in mobile too (stuck in Creators Update).

Here comes the problem. The API I used to enumerate network adapters is *[System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getallnetworkinterfaces?view=netcore-1.0)* which comes from *System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll* . If I select **Fall Creators Update** for both min and target versions, this code executes without a problem:

```
System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
```

In this case, if I go to definition of code in VS, I see that *Version=4.2.1.0* of the assembly is referenced, from this location:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.1.5\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll

But, when I downgraded min version to **Creators Update**, above code fails with this exception:

> System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.

This time, *Version=4.1.0.0* of the assembly is loaded from this location:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\system.net.networkinformation\4.1.0\ref\netcore50\System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll

I see that this version of the library does not implement the method I use. But the problem is, *System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll* is copied inside my application's package (like other System.XXX.dlls). Even though my desktop OS is capable of running newer version of this library, my app can load and execute only the one copied into its package.

In addition to that, [ApiInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.metadata.apiinformation) class which helps us to write version and platform specific code, does not even recognize this method or type. There is a very lightweight WinRT alternative ([Windows.Networking.Connectivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.connectivity)) which can be checked by this helper class. But it doesn't have the functionality I need. Therefore, I assume that when Microsoft talks about "version adaptive code", it means those WinRT APIs which does not get copied into app package (they are loaded from OS, I guess).

But, it should still be possible for me to achieve the goal I mentioned at the beginning. Because I need only one version of *System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll*. I added a dependency declaration in the manifest file:

```
<Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="10.0.16299.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.16299.0"/>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Mobile" MinVersion="10.0.15063.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.16299.0"/>
</Dependencies>
```

So my app will not run in a desktop which has an OS older than **Fall Creators Update** (which is capable of running my network adapter enumeration code). If I can copy newer dll to my app package and somehow make my app accept it (like it does when I upgrade min version to 16299), my problem will be solved. Since there are more than one hundred System.XXX.dll in my app package, there should be a way of using different versions of them, when running in different OS versions.

NOTE: There is also a NuGet library from Microsoft ([System.Net.NetworkInformation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.NetworkInformation/)). Referencing it didn't help me either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in this case stems from the fact, that this method was actually implemented only as of UWP Fall Creators Update, which is the first version that supports .NET Standard 2.0 and actually implements many of the previously unavailable .NET APIs. Previously this method was available albeit only without being implemented, see [this thread](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/9675).

The first option you have is to increase the min target to Fall Creators Update, which will however prevent your app from running on Windows 10 Mobile.

A better solution would be to use UWP API like:

```
Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation.GetConnectionProfiles()
```

This API should give you the information you need as well.

You can then use `ApiInformation` to call the correct API depending on the platform you are running.

Comment: Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation.GetConnectionProfiles(), unfortunately, is very limited compared to System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces().

Comment: On the other hand, the thread you refered, makes it clear that latter API looks like supported in Creators Update, but not actually implemented. They needed to explain this decision better in their documentation. In the light of this information, I know my options better. Thanks for the reference to this thread.